# I want to display specific infomation from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: grep, cat, proc

I want to Show the number of CPUs, the producer of the CPUs and the CPU model.

I have used `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to show the cpuinfo.
however i want to only display the needed information. e.g. `processor` `vendor_id` and `model name`.

I have tried using `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -Eni -e '\<(processor|vendor_id|model name)\>'` and the same command but replacing the `|` with `.*` .

Any ideas or solution?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need the angle brackets or the parentheses:

```
grep -E 'processor|vendor_id|model name' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: thanks i was just overcomplicating it hehe:)